# asp.net identity - SetPasswordHashAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to configure identity to work with custom provider. So far all good, I've created `UserStore`:

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<User>, IUserPasswordStore<User>
```

(with all methods implemented) and UserManager:

```
public UserManager(IUserStore<User> userStore)
        : base(userStore)
    { }
```

and User is my custom entity to hold users.

The problem is that in `UserStore` I have the following:

```
public async Task SetPasswordHashAsync(User user, string passwordHash)
```

From what I have understood, this is called before user is created, so all I should do here is:

```
public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(User user, string passwordHash)
{
    user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
}
```

... but this has to return a Task and I don't see anything asynchronous to be done here.

1. Why return type is Task for `SetPasswordHashAsync` and not just void?
2. How should I implement `SetPasswordHashAsync`?

I know I can do something like

```
public async Task SetPasswordHashAsync(User user, string passwordHash)
{
    user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
    await Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

... but isn't this synchronous? It is weird to see all other methods decorated with `async` Task and use `await`, and this one to return `Task.FromResult()`

Anyone?

Comment: I'm kinda at the same place. Where did you learn that you just had to set the hash in the user locally and not persist it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tasks do not have to be asynchronous. You can implement it as follows:

```
public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(User user, string passwordHash)
{
    user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: In .NET 4.6 it also has [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use.